# Can't get to work a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I wrote quite a simple function with some Jquery code in it and I can't get it to work for some reason.

What am I missing?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/VvQZxv)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">

  <p>Here should be five -> &nbsp;</p>

</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.onload = function(scope) {
    $('p').each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,"5"));
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: if you look in your console log it tells you all your problems. 1."Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" 2. "Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-modals' is an invalid sandbox flag."

Comment: @JoshStevens Now, I'm done with "Uncaught ReferenceError"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM in a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for quite a few reasons which are detailed in Angular docs and in a number of StackOverflow tickets.

**Recommended Reading:**

- ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)
- [Separating DOM manipulation from Angular controllers - Best Practice wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988547/separating-dom-manipulation-from-angular-controllers-best-practice-wanted)
- [Things I Wish I Were Told About Angular.js](http://ruoyusun.com/2013/05/25/things-i-wish-i-were-told-about-angular-js.html)

There's no `load` event in Angular controllers (and if there was it would be called with the `$scope.$on('load',function(){});` approach).

You should be using Angular data binding / interpolation here instead. Here's an example:

```
<p>Here should be five -> {{number}}</p>
```

And your controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.number = 5;
});
```

Comment: Probably better advice than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. The codepen has jqueryui and jquery in the wrong order, so you get an error. Also, the controller is called `MainCtrl` but in the HTML you have `DropdownCtrl`.
2. As for the actual mistake: just because you call a function `onload` doesn't mean that it actually executes when the controller starts. Take it out of that function and it'll do what you intended.

Like so:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $('p').each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,"5"));
    });
});
```

[New pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwYxKb?editors=101)

> While this might work in this instance, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM in the controller anyways. The first rule of Angular controllers is:
>
> > *"Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation."*
>
> [Read More at angularjs.org →](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Comment: Life saviour. Because of your comment I learned how to set up JQuery, how to set up Angular and how to start the snippet of code when the app loads. thank you tons ;)

Comment: @BillyLogan this can end up with Angular errors (they try to detect and error with you manipulating DOM in the controller). I don't recommend this approach.