# Why do we need Angular directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have searched and read a lot but still confused.

The question is, if i have a directive as below

```
.directive('someDirective',function(){
    return{
        scope:{},
        bindToController:{
            prop:"="
        },
        templateUrl:'myTemplate.html',
        controller:'directiveController'
    }
})

.controller('directiveController',function(){
    //Do controller stuff
})
```

Why would i need a link function ? I can pretty much bind the whole DOM to the controller for passing data.(Yes i know that controllers should be used when we want to expose a API function as per the angular docs). Pre angular 1.2 when bindToController did not exist it still made sense.

I have read there is pre and post method, this is where we should be doing stuff such as appending elements etc.But again I'm confused as why would i append stuff when i can just put it in "myTemplate.html".

Can you please give some relevant example where we should be using link and not the controller and what is the difference.

Comment: Did you consider that inner directive DOM isn't populated at the moment of controller init and there's nothing to operate on?

Comment: You could refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12570008/2435473 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676614/angularjs-link-vs-compile-vs-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

The directive's DOM is not rendered when the controller is initialised. If you want to set up listeners  ('$watch'), you need the link function, that is executed after DOM rendering.

Long answer:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 0):

I have not had occasion to use the pre- or post-link functions before but we use the link function all the time in our framework to get hold of a particular instance of a widget and then do something with it.

One widget that we have in our framework is a grid. Inside the grid we've given users the capability of editing the cell contents.

The users of our framework can add an attribute like this to their markup:

```
<sg-grid editable="true"></sg-grid>
```

We then look out for this attribute using the attrs parameter in the link function:

```
angular.module('sg.grid').directive('sgGrid', [

   restrict: 'E', // this is an element directive
   scope: {
      editable: @editable // each grid has its own, isolated scope
   },
   template: '<div class="sg-grid" ng-click="someFunction()"></div>', // we also add behaviour to the widget using events that are added to scope in the link()

   link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrls) {

      if (!_.isUndefined(attrs.editable)) { // underscore.js is used to check if it is defined

         if(attrs.editable === 'true' {
            addEditFunctionalityToCell();
         }

         addEditFunctionalityToCell() {
            ...
         }             
      }
      scope.someFunction = function() { ... } // this is bound to ng-click in the template
   }
   ...
]);
```

Comment: the question here is you could have put all this in controller as well and everything would fine.. so why not

Comment: Controllers should never be used to manipulate the DOM. See here for a good reason why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988547/separating-dom-manipulation-from-angular-controllers-best-practice-wanted